# Issue in working with JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, Count(MsThread.ThreadName) AS TotalPost, ThreadCategory

FROM ( MsThread LEFT JOIN MsPosts ON MsThread.ThreadName = MsPosts.ThreadName )

GROUP BY MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, MsThread.ThreadCategory;
```

I have checked previous threads mentioning the brackets in order to join to work in access, but mine still have this issue.

Comment: can you please add what error your getting.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] JOIN expression not supported. there's the error, i still dont get it why  :(

Comment: Are you using this to interact with a MySQL database in some way (as per the tag) or only Access?

Comment: using JSP to access them, but showing another invalid cursor state error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

I think the parentheses in the FROM statement is messing things up.

```
SELECT MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, Count(MsThread.ThreadName) AS TotalPost, ThreadCategory
FROM MsThread LEFT JOIN MsPosts ON MsThread.ThreadName = MsPosts.ThreadName
GROUP BY MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, MsThread.ThreadCategory;
```

Or this. It may be looking for LEFT "OUTER" JOIN.

```
SELECT MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, Count(MsThread.ThreadName) AS TotalPost, ThreadCategory
FROM MsThread LEFT OUTER JOIN MsPosts ON MsThread.ThreadName = MsPosts.ThreadName
GROUP BY MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, MsThread.ThreadCategory;
```

Comment: Some explanation of why these would be expected to work would be nice. I also can't even see the difference without some serious hunting, since these queries have so many terms.

Comment: no longer showing the problem but now having this problem, 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state